# Gemfire WAN Gateway-senders/receivers members

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

Within a cluster, we want to create members that are **neither** senders **nor** receivers, while having 1 sender/receiver in each cluster. We started up the sender/receiver in a given cluster first, no errors. As soon as we started up the member that's **neither** a sender **nor** a receiver, it raises this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create Region /data with
>   [gateway-sender-A] gateway sender ids because another cache has the
>   same region defined with [] gateway sender ids.

Some assumptions: 
- Replicated regions 
- Serial gateway-senders 
- manual-start is false for all gateway-senders

My guess is that since the member doesn't have a gateway-sender-id, it's complaining being blank, which I'm confused. I thought we can have members that are neither sender/receiver in a cluster. Can someone clarify?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

My old understanding was based on this graph, [image: WAN-Topology]

Where the 2 top left members were neither senders/receivers. **This is wrong**. The graph is a little misleading.

> You **CAN** set which members are **receivers** in cache xml but **CAN NOT** set
>   which members hosting the region are **senders**. In other words, having the  tag in a member doesn't mean that member is the sender, **it simply means that region has a sender in the cluster**.

Therefore, if you want a sender for a specified region, you must include the `<gateway-sender>` tag in all the members under the specified region for it to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using peer-to-peer configurations within a cluster, so all of these are peers but not clients. Then, the configuration for the same region needs to be identical, i.e. if member A has gateway sender 1, member B should have sender 1 in the gateway-sender-ids property.

This error will be thrown when the starting member figures out that somewhere in the cluster exists a region with the same name but not having the same configuration. And the error message tells the detailed reason.

To achieve "neither sender nor receiver", i think just simply not configure gateway sender/receiver on that specific instance will do.

Comment: For "neither sender nor receiver", I've didn't configure gateway sender/receiver, and that's throwing the error.